# Opencart htaccess in subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, opencart

How can I get this to work
This Openacart category and product rewrite is not work, account pages is work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Sub-domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://my.domain.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteRule login$ /index.php?route=account/login [L]
```

This work here, This Openacart category and product rewrite is work, account pages is not work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

# Sub-domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://my.domain.com$

RewriteRule login$ /index.php?route=account/login [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the surprise. Order htaccess file must be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

RewriteRule login$ /index.php?route=account/login [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1/ [L,QSA]
```

That subdomain guidance did not have any.